# Angular2 Webpack Express API Server

Tags: node.js, express, angular, webpack

I've started a project with this template: https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter

Now I want to add an babel exrpess server into the webpack "workflow".

Currently I cannot get it to work.

I want to run 1 "npm script" and have the entire workflow up and running. Meaning if I change a "frontend .ts file" I get live reload from my express server. And if I change a "backend .js file" my express server restarts.

What I have done so far:

- I added an express server and created an additional webpack.config file to build the babel scripts.

The Problem:

- I cannot "connect" both webpack "workflows". Meaning my express server is up and running but cannot serve the "frontend". And my webpack-dev-server (from the template) does not know anything about the express server.

I do not have any clue how to do this. Does anyone know a tutorial or could provide me with some intel so that I can set this up?

I hope I could make clear what I want and what my problem is.

Thanks for any help in advance
Robin

Comment: inside the repo from the link you supplied in your question, there is a section to learn about [Webpack and ES6 build tools](https://github.com/AngularClass/ES6-build-tools) thats what you want to read.

Comment: Also once you've read  that, the google search that will help will be Express Webpack connect middleware. Also webpack-hot-middleware

Comment: Thank you guys very much. I'll go ahead an read that stuff. Also thanks for the "keyword - webpack-hot-middleware". This should be enough to get me startet.